Anchor PDA Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account token 2022
i'm testing the Token Extension MetaData Pointer NFT using this example: https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/tokens/token-2022/nft-meta-data-pointer/anchor, but, instead of using a ramdom PDA account with the seed nft_authority, I created my own data account that receive additional elements, like an uri, and can update or close with another instruction.
So, this is my structure:
pub struct MintNft<'info> {
#[account(mut)]
pub signer: Signer<'info>,
pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
pub token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,
/// CHECK: We will create this one for the user
#[account(mut)]
pub token_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
#[account(mut)]
pub mint: Signer<'info>,
pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
#[account(
    seeds = [daccount.seed.as_bytes().as_ref()],
    bump = daccount.bump,
)]
pub daccount: Account<'info, Daccount>,

But, when try to execute my instruction, I'm receiving this error:
> Program logged: "Init metadata Fou56QKgKckRyzbhfcdqsqQhTgU1feEMxgM2S1RtAfWb"
> Fou56QKgKckRyzbhfcdqsqQhTgU1feEMxgM2S1RtAfWb's signer privilege escalated
> Program consumed: 95799 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned error: "Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account"

This is the part of the instruction that is failing:
let seeds: &[&[u8]] = &[daccount.seed.as_ref()];
let bump: &[&[u8]] = &[&[daccount.bump]];
let signer: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[seeds, bump];
msg!("Init metadata {0}", ctx.accounts.daccount.to_account_info().key);

// Init the metadata account
let init_token_meta_data_ix = 
&spl_token_metadata_interface::instruction::initialize(
    &spl_token_2022::id(),
    ctx.accounts.mint.key,
    ctx.accounts.daccount.to_account_info().key,
    ctx.accounts.mint.key,
    ctx.accounts.daccount.to_account_info().key,
    "Beaver".to_string(),
    "BVA".to_string(),
    "https://arweave.net/MHK3Iopy0GgvDoM7LkkiAdg7pQqExuuWvedApCnzfj0".to_string(),
);

invoke_signed(
    init_token_meta_data_ix,
    &[ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info().clone(), ctx.accounts.daccount.to_account_info().clone()],
    signer,
)?;

I double-checked in my tests that the program-derived address (PDA) I was deriving was the same as the one called in my instruction.
  let string = "demo"
  let seed = anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode(string);

  //call the PDA using the program ID and the seed
  const [daccount, _] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([seed], program.programId);

I believe the problem could be that I have already initialized the PDA account with another instruction, and here I'm attempting to call it again for initialization, but I'm not sure.

I found the problem. I discovered that my mistake was in how I generated the seed and the bump.
Here's the solution.
let seeds= ctx.accounts.daccount.seed.as_ref();
let bump = ctx.accounts.daccount.bump;
let signer: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[&[seeds, &[bump]]];

